# Update value of a struct from binary file

Tags: c, binaryfiles

Hey I'm new to binary files in C and i need help. I already have values stored in the files. I need to change the value of PrecoDia to a new value inputed by the user. The goal is to update the file with the new value.
This is my struct

```
typedef struct caravana{
char matricula[50];
char marca[50];
char modelo[50];
int ano;
char tipo[50];
int nPessoas;
float areaConv;
float precoDia;
char obs[50];
}CR;
```

This is the code i have so far.

```
void alterarPrecoCaravana(){

system("cls");

FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("caravanas.dat","r+b");

struct caravana c;

char mat[50];
float novoPreco;

if (fp == NULL) 
{ 
    printf("\nErro\n");
    exit(1);
}

listar();

printf("\n ----------------------- \n");
printf("\nIntroduza a matricula da caravana para alterar o preço: \n");
scanf("%s", mat);
printf("\n ----------------------- \n");
system("cls");

int flag=0;
while(fread(&c,sizeof(c),1,fp)){
    if(strcmp(mat,c.matricula)==0){
        flag =1;
        printf("\n ----------------------- \n");
        printf("\nIntroduza ao novo preço: \n");
        scanf("%f", &novoPreco);
        printf("\n ----------------------- \n");

        printf("\n Matricula - %s --------- Preço - %.2f",c.matricula,c.precoDia);
    }
}
if(!flag){
    printf("\n ----------------------- \n");
    printf("\n A Caravana não existe! \n");
    printf("\n ----------------------- \n");
    printf("\n Clique qualquer tecla para voltar \n");
    getch();

    menuAlterarInfoCaravanas();
    
}
printf("\n ----------------------- \n");
printf("\n Clique qualquer tecla para continuar \n");
printf("\n ----------------------- \n");
getch();

menuAlterarInfoCaravanas();

fclose(fp);
}
```

Now how can i change it in the file?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you already know how to write to binary files in general? I suppose as you can read them with `fread`, you can probably write them with [`fwrite`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite).

Comment: @Hulk, i've tried to write to file after the changes but nothing changes